# Making an R function "listen" for console input while running?

Tags: r, input

In R, is it possible to send a signal from the console to a running function, such that the function can do something?  Like, for example, exit and return current values?

Here's an example:  the function below bootstraps the standard error of a regression coefficient.  The function's verbosity shows how the variance is evolving.  It will asymptote to its lower bound.  I want to be able to send an `INTERUPTION SIGNAL` (somehow) that will stop the while loop and cause the function to cleanly exit.

```
example <- function(y, x){
  bvec <- c()
  while(TRUE){
    s <- sample(1:1000, replace = T)
    b <- lm(y[s]~x[s])$coef[2]
    bvec <- append(bvec, b)
    Sys.sleep(.1)
    print(var(bvec))
    if(INTERUPTION_SIGNAL){
      return(var(bvec))
    }
  }
}
x <- rnorm(1000)
y <- x+rnorm(1000)
```

In the dummy example, I could just run in global.  That's impractical in the real case.  It'd also be possible to write to disk after each iteration, but that would be slow.  I suppose I could add the following line above the verbosity: `tempout <<- var(bvec)`, which would work by putting the output in global.  But this feels a bit kludgy, and all rely on `^C`, which I'd rather not use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `keypress` package:

```
library(keypress)
x=0
while(TRUE){
x = x + 1
k = keypress(block=FALSE)
if(k!="none")break
}
```

Press any key to break out. I pressed "a" after about 49000 iterations:

```
> k
[1] "a"
> x
[1] 49263
```

You could check for a particular key if you want to break on pressing "Q", or print status on pressing "S" for example.

The documentation seems to imply it should return NA rather than "none" but I may be misreading it.